# How do I trace the source of FastCGI timeout isseus on PHP and IIS 7.5?

Tags: php, iis-7.5, fastcgi, timeout

I have a problem which I am hoping you experts can really help me find the root cause of.
I am getting random page time outs (which manifest as a 500 error) that I cannot find the root cause of.

PHP Version:

```
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2014 11:20:11)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

IIS Version:

```
Version 7.5.7600.16385
```

FastCGI:

```
C:\Users\lock>%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list config -section:system.webSe
rver/fastCgi
<system.webServer>
  <fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\php5\php-cgi.exe" activityTimeout="700">
      <environmentVariables>
      </environmentVariables>
    </application>
  </fastCgi>
</system.webServer>
```

I have turned on Failed Request Logs and I get the following for random pages:

```
C:\php5\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout
```

Time taken is 700007 msec

Last night, I created 2 files that simply run a very light query on MySQL and ODBC and ran them every minute. Checking this morning, the only file that resulted in a FailedRequest was the ODBC, so I am sure the problem is in connecting to ODBC. 
I created a new ODBC data source connecting to the same server and driver, but different database, and still get Timeouts, so I don't think it is the database itself. I'm going to try and see if it is the `odbc_pconnect` or the `odbc_exec` function that is timing out. I was able to replicate the issue through my own browser (it hung for almost 15 minutes before producing a FailedRequest Log) and at this time, I was able to fire up another browser and run the same page without issue, so I don't think it is anything to do with table locking on the database or what not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated- we really don't know where to go from here!